# FTP The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in

Tags: c#, ftp

I created an FTP, and I want to read some data using C# code. When the FTP has no username/password access, everything works perfectly. But when I put username and password, I get `The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in`.

I tried all the questions on Stack Overflow and the internet like using `.Normalize()`, and using `@username`, but I keep getting that error.

this is my code:

```
foreach (string fileNameInFTP in directories)
                {
                    //                string fileNameInFTP2 = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNameInFTP);
                    if ((!haveWeAlreadyParsedThisFile(fileNameInFTP)) && (fileNameInFTP.Contains("CustsExport")) && (!fileNameInFTP.EndsWith("Empty.xml")) && (!fileNameInFTP.Contains("DelCustsExport")))
                    {
                        string file = FTPAddress + "/" + fileNameInFTP;
                        Console.WriteLine(file);
                        List<Customer> customersList =
                        (
                            from e in XDocument.Load(file).Root.Elements("cust")
                            select new Customer
                            {
                                MemeberID = (int)e.Attribute("memberid"),
                                CustomerID = (int)e.Attribute("custid"),
                                FirstName = (string)e.Attribute("fname"),
                                LastName = (string)e.Attribute("lname"),
                                ShowsNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_noshow"),
                                VisitNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_resos"),
                                Cancellation = (int)e.Attribute("count_cancel"),
                                MobileNumber = (string)e.Element("phone").Attribute("phonenumber")
                                /*Projects =
                                (
                                    from p in e.Elements("projects").Elements("project")
                                    select new Project
                                    {
                                        ProjectCode = (string)p.Element("code"),
                                        ProjectBudget = (int)p.Element("budget")
                                    }).ToArray()*/
                            }).ToList();
```

#### Note:

I am able to access the FTP because the `directories` variable is the list of the files in the FTP, and when I debug the code, I can see that it **has** the files, but the exception accurs in this line:

```
                    List<Customer> customersList =
                    (
                        from e in XDocument.Load(file).Root.Elements("cust")
                        select new Customer
                        {
                            MemeberID = (int)e.Attribute("memberid"),
                            CustomerID = (int)e.Attribute("custid"),
                            FirstName = (string)e.Attribute("fname"),
                            LastName = (string)e.Attribute("lname"),
                            ShowsNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_noshow"),
                            VisitNumber = (int)e.Attribute("count_resos"),
                            Cancellation = (int)e.Attribute("count_cancel"),
                            MobileNumber = (string)e.Element("phone").Attribute("phonenumber")
                            /*Projects =
                            (
                                from p in e.Elements("projects").Elements("project")
                                select new Project
                                {
                                    ProjectCode = (string)p.Element("code"),
                                    ProjectBudget = (int)p.Element("budget")
                                }).ToArray()*/
                        }).ToList();
```

**In other words: I am able to read the names of the files, but not the content of them.**

Comment: @DJKRAZE why are you talking about the `upload` ?, my problem is nothing about upload.

Comment: Sound like the FTP server is returning 530. Where inn your code are you connecting to the server?

Comment: The problem is that `XDocument.Load(file)` is trying to make a *new connection* to the FTP server, and it doesn't have the necessary credentials. So it throws an exception.

Comment: @JimMischel so what is the solution please?

Comment: I'd consider creating a `FtpWebRequest` to get the file, and when you get the response, do `XmlDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream())`. Something like that. I don't have working code for you, but that approach should work.

Comment: You might try the FTP url with the username and password in the URL. That is, if you're trying to download `ftp://ftp.foo.com/path/filename`, you can encode the username and password like this: `ftp://username:password@ftp.foo.com/path/filename`. That might do it for you. See Section 3.2 of [RFC 1738](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/doc/rfc/rfc1738.txt) for more info. You would pass that URL to `XDocument.Load`. Note, however, that the password is sent in the clear.

Comment: @JimMischel Your solution works well, could you post an answer to accept it please? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the user name and password on the FTP URL. For example, if you want to download `/path/filename` from `ftp://ftp.foo.com`, you can encode the user name and password like this:

```
ftp://username:password@ftp.foo.com/path/filename
```

You should be able to construct such a URL for the file you're trying to download. Then pass that URL to `XDocument.Load`.

Note, however, that the password is sent in the clear (i.e. no encryption, etc.).

See Section 3.2 of [RFC 1738](ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/doc/rfc/rfc1738.txt) for more info.

Comment: Hi Jim how does this work if the username contains space characters?

Comment: @user3095420 perhaps add quotes to the parameter. I've never tried it. If " doesn't work, try '.

Comment: Or, perhaps try URL encoding the space as %20